# use webscraping to extract Tesla revenue data

Tags: python-requests-html

AttributeError:'dataframe' object has no attribute to'Tesla Revenue'

this is what i tried and the output

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please always post code and the error message as text and format it as code.

Comment: why do you call tesla_revenue dataframe twice,  if you want to see the last 5 elements tesla_revenue.tail() would be enough

Answer (score 0):

**Hi try this code:**

```
#3
tesla_tables = soup.find_all("table")
for index, table in enumerate(tesla_tables):
    if("Tesla Quarterly Revenue" in str(table)):
        tesla_table_index = index

tesla_revenue = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Revenue"])
for row in tesla_tables[tesla_table_index].tbody.find_all("tr"):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    date = col[0].text 
    revenue = col[1].text 
    tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.append({"Date": date, 
    "Revenue": revenue}, ignore_index = True)

tesla_revenue["Revenue"] = tesla_revenue['Revenue'].str.replace(',|\$',"")

tesla_revenue.dropna(inplace=True)
tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue[tesla_revenue['Revenue'] != ""]

tesla_revenue.tail()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).